# Connection using "Profile '<DEFAULT>'" failed with error: "unable to get local issuer certificate"."

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssl-certificate, databricks, vscode-extensions, azure-databricks

I am trying to use vscode(installed in host windows machine) with WSL(windows subsystem linux).

I have installed databricks extension so that i can trigger job from VScode itself in azure databricks cluster.

When i try to configure and connect to databricks i see this error "**Connection using "Profile ''" failed with error: "unable to get local issuer certificate".**"

Comment: You might need to import the CA certificate into the WSL environment. Try it once.